# How do I run a do-while loop, which is checking a value in a JSON with PHP?

Tags: php, json, api, while-loop

I am trying to create a do-while loop, which checks if a value is still present in a JSON - my basic idea is of repeatedly calling an API while it does have a particular value - at the end when the JSON doesn't have the value, the loop will finish running.

Is this possible? How should I check if a value is present in the JSON response?

---

Here's what my response looks like - (btw I will be looking for the value 'offset' every-time)

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "recYxbvL2ScZXt8Pf",
      "fields": {
        "Display": "1) ADWANI AVINASH NIRANJANKUMAR (A2019) (CP) (NN) || recYxbvL2ScZXt8Pf"
      },
      "createdTime": "2021-09-25T13:11:43.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "reccXiBSeyMqLAVN0",
      "fields": {
        "Display": "2) AGARWAL NEEDHI SUNIL (A2015) (CP) (NN) || reccXiBSeyMqLAVN0"
      },
      "createdTime": "2021-09-25T13:11:43.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": "rec7G80Xihuc7cLwu",
      "fields": {
        "Display": "3) AGARWAL UMESH LUXMANLAL (F1990) (CP) (NN) || rec7G80Xihuc7cLwu"
      },
      "createdTime": "2021-09-25T13:11:43.000Z"
    }
    .
    .
    .
  ],
  "offset": "itrwUFrVOdUJauKgs/recOA1j1y2VaRbTcs" //this value
}
```

Comment: Tangential, but did you ask [a similar question about an hour or so ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69406196/how-to-keep-calling-api-requests-until-json-response-does-not-contain-a-specific)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how to do this:

```php
<?php

const DUMMY_JSON_RESPONSES = [
  '{"id":"response 1","offset":"itrwUFrVOdUJauKgs/recOA1j1y2VaRbTcs"}',
  '{"id":"response 2","offset":"itrwUFrVOdUJauKgs/recOA1j1y2VaRbTcs"}',
  '{"id":"response 3","offset":"itrwUFrVOdUJauKgs/recOA1j1y2VaRbTcs"}',
  '{"id":"response 4"}'
];

function dummyApiRequest() {
  static $i = 0;

  if( $i >= count( DUMMY_JSON_RESPONSES ) ) {
    $i = 0;
  }

  return DUMMY_JSON_RESPONSES[ $i++ ];
}

// this is the relevant code part:
do {
  // do API request
  $jsonResponse = dummyApiRequest();
  // decode JSON response into an associative array
  $response = json_decode( $jsonResponse, true );
  // json_decode() will return null on error
  if( $response !== null ) {
    // output dummy id key for demonstration purposes
    var_dump( $response[ 'id' ] );
  }
}
while( $response !== null && isset( $response[ 'offset' ] ) );
```